# How to plot histogram in timeseries with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am new to gnuplot and I would appreciate some help to understand how I can plot a timeseries histogram

My data looks like this:

```
#Date    Time     WKB
20130206 11:45:57 4544
20130206 11:45:57 5113 
20130206 11:45:57 5117 
20130206 11:45:57 5123 
20130206 11:45:57 5129 
20130206 11:45:57 5151 
...................
```

I have data around 2 days.

What I need is to plot following charts:

1. Average of WKB for x minues (for e.g. 5 minutes) in histogram
2. Cumulative sum of WKB for x minues (for e.g. 5 minutes) in histogram

This my current script:

```
set xdata time
set xtics 36000
set timefmt "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S"
set format x "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"
plot using 1:3 title smooth cumulative
```

I am sure I am missing a lot of things. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, gnuplot just isn't well suited to handle data processing tasks such as these.  You probably *could* come up with a solution, but it would be extremely messy and super hard to use.  Fortunately, gnuplot can read from pipes from other programs -- So the easiest solution is to write a simple script to process the input data and write it to standard output.  I'd choose python:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
from collections import defaultdict
import sys

def datetime_2_epoch(dt):
    return int(time.mktime(dt.timetuple()))

def epoch_2_datetime(epoch):
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(epoch)

data = defaultdict(list)
with open(sys.argv[1]) as fin:
    for line in fin: #Parse file 1 line at a time
        timestr,datastr = line.rsplit(None,1)
        try:
            dt = datetime.strptime(timestr,"%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S")
            val = float(datastr)
        except ValueError: #couldn't read this line.  must be a comment or something.
            continue

        bin = datetime_2_epoch(dt)//300 #300 = 60*5 -- 5 minute bin size
        data[bin].append(val)

for bin,lst in sorted(data.items()):
    cum_sum = sum(lst)
    avg = cum_sum/len(lst)
    print epoch_2_datetime(bin*300),avg,cum_sum
```

This will format your datafile (run on your sample data) as:

```
2013-02-06 11:45:00 5029.5 30177.0
2013-02-06 11:55:00 5029.5 30177.0
```

which can be plotted with boxes in gnuplot:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
set yrange [0:*]
plot '<python test.py test.dat' u 1:3 w boxes title "5 minute average"
```

or

```
plot '<python test.py test.dat' u 1:4 w boxes title "5 minute sum"
```

Comment: Thanks for the python program I will give it a try

Comment: @mgilson I disagree! Even at that time you could "easily" handle such tasks with gnuplot 4.6.0. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Even with gnuplot 4.6.0 (at the time of OP's question) it was/is "easily" possible to handle timeseries histograms with gnuplot *only*.
Check the following example.
It generates a file with random data (normal distributed times around now) and puts it into bins of 5 minutes.
Check `help smooth unique` und `help smooth frequency`.

**Script:** (tested with gnuplot 4.6.0 (March 2012) and 5.4.1 (Dec. 2020)

```
### time data histograms
reset

FILE = "SO14770053.dat"

# create some random test data
set print FILE
    now = time(0)
    do for [i=1:1000] {
        print sprintf("%s %d", strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S",now+invnorm(rand(0))*3600), int(rand(0)*2000)+3000)
    }
set print

myBinWidth = 300   # 300 sec = 5 min
Bin(col)   = floor(timecolumn(col)/myBinWidth)*myBinWidth

set boxwidth myBinWidth absolute
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S"
set format x "%d.%m.\n%H:%M"
set xtics out
set style fill transparent solid 0.3

set multiplot layout 2,1
    set ytics 500
    plot FILE u (Bin(1)):3 smooth unique w boxes lc rgb "red" ti "Average in 5 min bins"

    set ytics 50000
    plot FILE u (Bin(1)):3 smooth freq w boxes lc rgb "blue" ti "Sum in 5 min bins"
unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]