# Group data by week

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have data of the following form. I want to count the number of occurrences by week (i.e. group by week).

```
"CaseNumber"    "StartDate"             "PatAge"    "CallerZip" 
"a"             "7/4/2017 11:21:00 PM"  "10"         "12345"
"b"             "7/5/2017 3:38:03 PM"   "10"        "12245"
"c"             "7/15/2017 3:38:03 PM"  "10"        "12245"
```

I can convert this file to the following form in another program, but I want to know if there's a way to do it inside of gnuplot.

```
 Week     Count
  1         2
  2         1
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770053/gnu-plot-how-to-plot-histogram-in-timeseries) suggests it might be easier to convert (and then graph) in another program. My question is different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46405955/gnuplot-group-by-days) because I cannot get the week by truncating `"StartDate"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gnuplot has a time format %W (see `help time_specifier`)

```
  %W           week of the year (week starts on Monday)
```

You can use this to read in your dates using strptime() to convert from string to numerical seconds and then using strftime() to go back from seconds to week #. To see how it works try this sequence of commands

```
  date1 = "7/15/2017 3:38:03 PM"
  s1 = strptime("%m/%d/%Y", date1)
  print s1
         1500076800.0
  week = strftime("%W", s1)
  print week
         28
```

The input function timecolumn(column,format) works the same way as strptime except that it reads from a column of input data rather than from a string variable.
To put all this into a single evaluation while reading your data file it is easiest to define a function.  I will show using this function to simply plot the week number and leave it to you to use the week number for something else as you say you want

```
  weekno(column) = int(strftime("%W", timecolumn(column,"\"%m/%d/%Y")))

  plot "file" skip 1 using 0:(weekno(2)) with points
```

Notes:

- The time format in the definition of weekno() contains an escaped double quote because your data format has quotes around the date string.
- `skip 1` is a way to ignore the header comments in the first line of data
- You can see in the plot fragment below that the function is returning week 27 for your first two dates and week 28 for the third date.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I understood your question that you basically want to create a histogram of occurrences with a binning interval of a week.
You can do this using `smooth freq`. Check `help smooth`.
The binning interval will be one week or `3600*24*7` seconds.
I slightly modified your time format. This 12h-time format with `AM/PM` "always" create problems and cannot be read by gnuplot (not yet, but in one of the next versions. See comment here: [gnuplot: how to convert 12h time format into 24h time format?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59552645/7295599)).

**Code:**

```
### count occurrences by week
reset session

myTimeFmt = '"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"'
StartDate = '"01/01/2017 00:00:00"'
EndDate =   '"12/31/2017 23:59:59"'

# create some test data
# function for creating a random date between two dates
t(date_str) = strptime(myTimeFmt, date_str)
Random_Date(d0,d1) = strftime(myTimeFmt,rand(0)*(t(d1)-t(d0)) + t(d0))
Alphabet = "abcdedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
set print $Data
    do for [i=1:200] {
        rand26 = int(rand(0)*26)+1
        RandomChar = Alphabet[rand26:rand26]
        print sprintf('"%s" %s "%d" "%d"',RandomChar,Random_Date(StartDate,EndDate), \
        int(rand(0)*100)+1, int(rand(0)*9e6)+1e6)
    }
set print
# print $Data   # uncomment if you want to see the random data

set style fill solid 1.0
set boxwidth 0.7

set xlabel "Weeks after start date"
set xtics out
set ylabel "Occurrences per week"
set ytics out

# binning for histogram
bin(n) = floor((timecolumn(n,myTimeFmt)-strptime(myTimeFmt,StartDate))/3600/24/7)+1

# either print a table or directly plot the result
set table $Occurrences
    plot $Data u (bin(2)) smooth freq
unset table
print $Occurrences

plot $Data u (bin(2)) smooth freq w boxes notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]